# Import "pytube" could not be resolved pylance (repotMissingImport)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, pytube, pylance

from pytube import Youtube

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWrBy.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should not post pictures of code on this site.  Please take the time to read how to ask a good question in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced this problem:

[image]

Please refer to the following to check the installation process of the module:

1. If you have multiple python environments, please check whether the VS Code terminal is using the selected python environment (shown in the lower left corner of VS Code), if they are not the same, please open a new VS Code terminal. (`python --version`)

   [image]
2. Install the module "pytube". (`pip install pytube`)
3. Check the location of the module: (`pip show pytube`)

   [image]
4. Then, please reload VS Code to make it recognize this module：(`F1`, `Developer: Reload Window`)

   [image]

Reference: [Python environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

Your Python interpreter may also be found on the [bottom right corner of VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfq3R.png)

Comment: Please [edit] this answer with a screenshot of where in the IDE one might find this information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33342050)